# Build process in "Release" gets stuck for UWP application

Tags: .net, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a UWP application that builds and runs perfectly in Debug mode, but when I try to build it in **Release** (using .NET Native), the build process gets stuck somewhere and never finishes.

The project is here: https://github.com/SuperJMN/ParrotDiscoReflight.git. You can try yourself. Clone the **master** branch and a compile in **Release** mode.

I tried to put the build logging to the "Diagnostic" level, and it doesn't show anything strange. In fact, it seems it's not the build stage what is stuck, but a later stage related to "ilc.exe"

I don't have a clue of what's the problem.

Comment: Your `PackageReference ` looks well, Have you tried clean the solution or dele `bin` and `obj` folder before run release?

Comment: How long did you wait? "build stage what is stuck" Native toolchain is extremely slow and it may build for several minutes.

Comment: I tested with blank app, so it build very soon.

Comment: @AccessDenied I've let it run for more than 1 hour! the application is way small. The build process shouldn't last more than 4-5 minutes.

Comment: Without example it's hard to guess. Once I had similar problem when had many threads to build the project and it always get into deadlock, untill I changed it to 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Qea.png

Comment: @AccessDenied Could you please try to build in Release? The code is here: https://github.com/SuperJMN/ParrotDiscoReflight.git (master branch)

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Could you please try to build in Release? The code is here: https://github.com/SuperJMN/ParrotDiscoReflight.git (master branch)

Comment: I have run your project  in debug model but it throw exception.

Comment: Which Exception? Can you try to build in Release?

Comment: I can confirm, it hangs in release mode when app configuration is set to build. It starts consuming CPU and 2 Gb of memory. Submit bug here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Comment: @Access Denied Thanks for confirming! I sent the problem report some days ago: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/365294/building-uwp-in-release-gets-stuck-build-process-n.html

Comment: And it does not hang without native toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem is that the .NET Native compiler has a known incompatibility with System.Reactive 4.1+. The only workaround for now is to add an explicit reference to System.Reactive 4.0.0.

For more info: https://twitter.com/pmatmic/status/1057281313781108738